# Find the sum of the coefficients and the constant of the product (down below)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Given: $(x^3 + 3x - 1)(2x^4-5x^2+3x + 2)$ find the sum of the coefficients and the constant of the product.

I was curious if there was a formula I could use to possibly solve it? If you are able to solve it, I would love to see how and if you have any possible sources to recommend for me to expand on my learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the coefficients of any polynomial, factored or not, is calculated simply by plugging in $x = 1$.

$(1 + 3 - 1)(2 - 5 + 3 + 2) = (3)(2) = 6$.

As for the constant, you should visualize this as just multiplying the constants of the two polynomials, or when $x = 0$:

$(-1)*(2) = -2$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for any polynomial $P(x)$ the sum of the coefficients is $P(1)$, and the constant term is $P(0)$.